# using xdmp:document-insert and specify xml encoding

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a xquery endpoint which loads the file coming into the database using xdmp:document-insert.. and this fails when trying to upload an XML document which has "ISO-8859-1" encoding.. Following is my code

```
declare  %rapi:transaction-mode("update") function repoLoad:post($context as map:map, $params  as map:map,$input as document-node()*) as document-node()*
{

    let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename("upload")
    let $contentType := xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("upload")

    let $uri := "/documents/"

    let $_ := xdmp:document-insert($uri, xdmp:get-request-field("upload"),(xdmp:default-permissions()), ("raw"))

    return $uri

};
```

This fails for xml documents which are not UTF8 encoded.. I get the following exception.. any workaround ??

> Error: AppRequestTask::run: XDMP-DOCUTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape
>   sequence at  line 1 -- document is not UTF-8 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can generate the payload with an XML prolog that declares the encoding, that should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
... rest of the document ...
```

Otherwise, you could try something like the following on the server to generate the XML document for insertion:

```
xdmp:document-insert(
    $uri,
    xdmp:binary-decode(
        xdmp:unquote(
            xdmp:get-request-field("upload"), (), "format-binary"
            ),
        "ISO-8859-1"
        ),
    ... collection, permissions, and other arguments ...
    )
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Actually the xml file that I upload does have teh XML prolog
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE ClinicalTrial SYSTEM "TrialTrove4_v2.1.dtd"[]><ClinicalTrial id="5936"> ...
```
The second solution will not work for me as I cannot assume everything coming is XML,

Comment: On the first solution, are you sure the declared encoding is correct?  Sometimes files don't declare the correct encoding.  You could try xdmp:unquote() with "format-xml" instead of "format-binary" and no xdmp:binary-decode() to see if that works.  Regarding the second solution, I assume you could branch on $contentType to determine when to apply that approach.

Comment: To my knowledge MarkLogic has always ignored the declare encoding. With repair option enabled, it will sniff the first few lines of characters to make an educated guess, but otherwise use the default encoding of UTF-8. Limited details can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get.

Comment: Years ago I wrote a few functions to intelligently sniff the encoding at ingest, but slows down ingest quite a bit: http://markmail.org/message/jiuf4zk5s3gyflic. Functions like http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:encoding-language-detect might make that a bit easier, haven't tried..